# Search workflow name in the session log file using the linux command

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, find

I have a session log file generated by informatica powercenter, I need to search and print  the workflow name with the file name ..I am using the below command, but it is hardcoded .. what could the possible generic command.

```sh
grep -e "workflow: \[wfk_load_oltp_stg_data\]" -o -H filename.log
```

note : here the text "wfk" is common in all the logs file .. any help  how I write the regx t pickup the workflow name

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question, could you please also post samples of input and expected output too in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Just do grep -e "workflow: \[wfk_" -o -H filename.log

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sh
grep -Po 'workflow:\s*\[\Kwfk[^][]*(?=])' filename.log
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ucMs5F/1)

**Explanation**

```sh
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  workflow:                'workflow:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  wfk                      'wfk'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^][]*                   any character except: ']', '[' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]                        ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```